# How can I make a chat function in a website in phoenix framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to make a chat function in my website. When user log in, user can send a message to another user. I have User, Chat and Message Models.

```
schema "chats" do

belongs_to :user, Myapp.User
has_many :messages, Myapp.Message
timestamps

end

schema "users" do

has_many :chats, Myapp.Chat
has_many :messages, Myapp.Message

timestamps

end

schema "messages" do

belongs_to :chats, Myapp.User
belongs_to :users, Myapp.User


timestamps
end
```

I have assigned user to chats so that when user make a new chat, user_id of sender would be assigned. I am struggling with assigning user who receives a message.. how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to model chat.
One of the simplest is to create only one to one chats:

```
schema "chats"
  belongs_to :user1, Myapp.User
  belongs_to :user2, Myapp.User
  has_many :messages, Myapp.Message
```

Then user doesn't have to have messages, only chats:

```
schema "users"
  has_many :chats, Myapp.Chat

schema "messages" do
  belongs_to :chat, Myapp.User
  belongs_to :from_user, Myapp.User
  belongs_to :to_user, Myapp.User
```

If you want to create real time chat application you should also check out Phoenix channels and this example chat application: https://github.com/chrismccord/phoenix_chat_example

Comment: Thanks. Can I ask you one more question about fields of schema? So in chats table, user 1 and user 2 will be the columns referencing user_id... is that right?

Comment: thanks, can I ask you how can I submit id of user 1 and user 2 params to database?? For user 1, I assigned user to get user_id but I am struggling submitting user 2 id.. any suggestions?

Comment: You need to get the user somehow from the database. If one user wants to write to another how does he find him? By username? Then just search for a user with given username and add the id.

Comment: how about using profile? I have profile model and one of its columns is user_id.  So when user 1 clicks a link in user 2's profile, it passes user 2's user_id from profile. To do this, how should i change chat controller? adding a private function that checks if current_path is user_profile_path and current_user.id is not equal to profile.user id, it gets user_id from the profile page. Do you think is that going to work?? thanks a lot for your answers.